# converting curl to ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, parsing, curl

I have a curl call like this

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: **************" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ************" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'username=cooldude6' \
  --data-urlencode 'password=p_n7!-e8' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/login
```

I want this to make an ajax call. I know how to add the headers but what i don't know is what to do with the "urlencode" arguments.

This is the method that i wrote to take care of the headers

```
function getResponse(type, url, data, responseHandler) {
        var result = $.ajax(
        {
            url: url,
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            type: type,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            async: false,
            beforeSend: setHeader
        });


    function setHeader(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-Application-Id','**************');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', '**************');
    }       
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will urlencode things as needed already. You can just pass {username: 'cooldude6', password: 'yourpass'} as the `data` arg of the ajax call.